# Simple C# Async Await - Process List Asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Please be kind to me as I know this subject has been repeatedly brought up.  I just can't get my brain around it.  I have a really simple job:  go through a list of files and process each one.  Wait for them all to be finished, then run a Finalize routine.   I am getting a warning asking me to add an Await operator to the result of the call.  Am I doing this right?  Here is my code:

```
async void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await processFiles();
        Finalize();
    }   


async Task<int> processFiles()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string fileName in listBox1.Items)
        {

              process(fileName);
              i++;

        }
        return (i);
    }

async Task void process(string fileName)
    {  //  
       // read a CSV file into an SQL database
    }

 private void btnSelectFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   // get the files into the list box
        string procesingDirectory = "C:\temp";
        FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        FBD.SelectedPath = procesingDirectory;
        FBD.Description = "Select Files";
        FBD.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath);
            Array.Sort(files);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                if (file.IndexOf(".txt") > 0)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(file);
                }
                if (file.IndexOf(finder) > 0)
                {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is with the downvote and no comment?  I've spent hours upon hours reading up on this and trying different things and I'm still stuck.  Isn't SO for help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure since you don't provide details on the actual async work done in the process method but should be something like this

```
async Task<int> processFiles()
{
    var processingTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (string fileName in listBox1.Items)
    {
          processingTasks.Add(process(fileName));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);
    return processingTasks.Count;
}
```

The compiler is complaining that you are using async method but do not use the async feature. It seems that you want to resume when all the tasks are done. Still hard to tell without the actual code. Your current implementation does fire and forget approach and does not await for the tasks to complete. If this is what you want you may simply make the method synchronous and the process method will run asynchronously if it is implemented correctly.

Comment: Nice!  Thank you. So the Await should be in the same method as the async call?

Comment: async in front of the method signifies that you are going to use await in that method. Now where should the await be depends on the problem you are solving. Typically you await operations that require some form of IO (reading/writing files, calling a database, calling a web service). In addition it is usually the case that all the methods calling an async method are also async.